# error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/ansi-regex/-/ansi-regex-5.0.1.tgz: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.yarnpkg.com"

Tags: docker, yarnpkg

I was following the guide in Docker official guide, **Guides->Get started->Part 2: Containerize an application**.

1. git clone https://github.com/docker/getting-started.git
2. then I created a Dockerfile with content as below:

   ```
   # syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
   FROM node:18-alpine
   WORKDIR /app
   COPY . .
   RUN yarn install --production
   CMD ["node", "src/index.js"]
   EXPOSE 3000
   ```
3. I tried to build it, but an error happened

```
docker build -t getting-started .
```

Error information are as follows :

```
[+] Building 101.8s (12/12) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => resolve image config for docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1                                                                                                                             13.7s
 => CACHED docker-image://docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1@sha256:9ba7531bd80fb0a858632727cf7a112fbfd19b17e94c4e84ced81e24ef1a0dbc                                                         0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:18-alpine                                                                                                                      11.9s
 => [1/4] FROM docker.io/library/node:18-alpine@sha256:b3f383c13d71066a4e2380d42f4563ac14ac76b3035a5bea4db84209e14665d5                                                                 0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2.49kB                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => CACHED [2/4] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => CACHED [3/4] COPY . .                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => ERROR [4/4] RUN yarn install --production                                                                                                                                          20.8s
------
 > [4/4] RUN yarn install --production:
#10 0.456 yarn install v1.22.19
#10 0.516 [1/4] Resolving packages...
#10 0.689 [2/4] Fetching packages...
#10 5.792 error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/ansi-regex/-/ansi-regex-5.0.1.tgz: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.yarnpkg.com".
#10 5.792 info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/app/yarn-error.log".
#10 5.792 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c yarn install --production]: exit code: 1
```

Here is my enviroment :

- WIN10 Family Edition 22H2
- Docker Desktop 4.15.0 (93002)
  I've tried to add command

```
yarn config set registry http://registry.npm.taobao.org/
```

in the Dockerfile, but this still happened. The modified Dockerfile is as below:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM node:18-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN yarn config set registry http://registry.npm.taobao.org/ && yarn install --production
CMD ["node", "src/index.js"]
EXPOSE 3000
```

Still didn't fix the error. And I can't find the log file **/app/yarn-error.log**

Answer (score 1):

You may want to read  [docker build giving error in "yarn install"](https://github.com/docker/getting-started/issues/56) which discusses the problem in detail.

To summarize, this is a network and security problem and although there appears to be ways to get around this by changing the contents of the **Dockerfile**, the easiest way is to simply connect to a different network.

I tested this with two Windows 10 computers connected to the same network (at my home, not a corporate network) and both computers failed at this point in the docker build.

I then disconnected both computers from that network and connected them to a mobile network and successfully built and ran the **getting-started** image on both computers.

Please note, I did not have to change anything in the docker getting-started tutorial.